# Javascript screen size

Tags: javascript, iframe

**Can I use some sort of JS script to take advantage of the size control here in the url?**

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://media.embed.ly/1/frame?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitch.tv%2Fgamemode_mc_&amp;width=1280&amp;height=1280&amp;secure=true&amp;key=0202f0ddb5a3458aabf520e5ab790ab9&amp;"
```

*(My goal here is actually to place this Twitch feed as a background to my webpage - resizing the actual content of the iframe is actually a very unusual but additional treat here, because of the way Twitch's url works!)*

To be clear, I'm very early in my learning of JS, and looking for a beginner solution to take the browser window size to dynamically control the parameters in this url to control the size of the content in this iframe.

```
width=1280&amp;height=1280&amp;
```

are the key lines here. I need to make these measurements follow the viewport size instead of being static. What method is best to do this?

Comment: it looks like the viewport size is hardcoded anyway, how and why should it change?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly set the `src` to your iframe programmatically, and build the `src` url based on variables such as your viewport size.

You can try something like this:

```
function loadIframe() {
    var url = '',
        viewportWidth  = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    url = 'https://media.embed.ly/1/frame?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitch.tv%2Fgamemode_mc_&amp;width=' + viewportWidth + '&amp;height=' + viewportHeight + '&amp;secure=true&amp;key=0202f0ddb5a3458aabf520e5ab790ab9&amp;';

    document.getElementById('myIframe').src = url;
}
```

Then you can make the iframe reload when the window is resized and when the window is done loading:

```
window.onload = loadIframe;
window.onresize = loadIframe;
```

However I would actually recommend using jQuery to help you do this as you would be able bind to cross-browser events easier.